# How to update data in datastore, saved in the memcache?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore, datastore

I am working on a datastore project on which I have to work with `memcache`. But because I never used `memcache` before so I am confused with it. I followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/memcache/) link and successfully saved and retrieved values from memcache.

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
$value = $request->getContent();
return $memcache->set($key, $value);
```

and

```
$memcache = new Memcache;
return $memcache->get($key);
```

So this is enough for me when I want to only get a user's detail and save it into the `memcache`. But the problem is with inserting the values from `memcache` to database. Can anyone please guide me how should I approach it. Whether I should save the user's edits into the `memcache` when he makes them and when try to logout then I should first save all the changes into the datastore or there are some other solutions available to make changes later? Please help me.

Comment: read more about memcached. you will realize its a bad idea to not save immediately to datastore because memcache has no guarantees so you will lose data and that is by design.

Comment: Hi @ZigMandel, I actually wanted to save frequent api calls to update or insert data. Which would be cost effective I think. Can you please tell me What should I do create my system cost effective?

Comment: yes you could keep commits in memcached but wont help you unless you are committing many times per second. it's possible but you need to think very well when to commit it. definitely not on "logout"

Comment: How can we keep commits in the `memcache`. Is it the same way that we save `memcache`? I mean I should store the commit instance in the `memcache` and set some kind of interval to update the entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think of it as "inserting data from memcache to the database" - there is nothing specially for this. You're just inserting into the database (in the usual way) data which just happened to be retrieved from memcache.

Comment: Hi @Dan... I am stuck because I want to reduce api calls to write data into the database. For example I have a user entity I need to fetch its information & update it as per your request. But each time user updates even a single field it would make a request to datastore. How should I prevent it?

Comment: does not seem to answer the question (but is a good tip for the comments, not as an answer)

Comment: @MKB: don't try to use memcache as buffer for **writing** into the datastore -  you will corrupt your data as memcache information can dissappear at any time (and will, eventually) and memcache ops are not transaction - protected.

Comment: Okay @DanCornilescu I'll keep it in my mind but is there any other way that may help me?

Comment: If you think that you could reduce the datastore write api calls via memcache buffering it means that your info update logic should be improved to eliminate the redundant writing ops.  If there are no redundant writes then you'd gain nothing.